# MySQL Dockerized Database Appears Empty - Unable to Access Data

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker

I am currently working on a Spring Boot web API project using Gradle with a MySQL database, and both my backend application and database are Dockerized. In the development of my application, I followed an example provided by my university. The example initializes the database within the application itself using a class named DatabaseDataInitializer. This class populates initial dummy data for a TodoEntity in the TodoRepository.

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DatabaseDataInitializer {

private TodoRepository todoRepository;

@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void populateDatabaseInitialDummyData() {
    if (todoRepository.count() == 0) {
        todoRepository.save(TodoEntity.builder().title("Plan vacations").done(false).build());
        todoRepository.save(TodoEntity.builder().title("Clean kitchen").done(false).build());
        todoRepository.save(TodoEntity.builder().title("Study React").done(false).build());
        todoRepository.save(TodoEntity.builder().title("Shopping 
        groceries").done(false).build());
    }
}
```

However, in my implementation, I am facing an issue where my MySQL Dockerized database seems empty even though I did the same steps. Both my backend application and MySQL database are Dockerized, and when attempting to access a specific endpoint, for example, /products, the logs in my Docker backend container indicate an error stating that the table 'products' does not exist:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'webstore.users' doesn't exist
```

It's worth noting that since I started using Docker recently I do not have a Docker Compose File because I am not sure what it does which may be the issue.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM gradle:7.5.0-jdk17
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY ./build/libs/WebShop-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ./

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "java ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar WebShop-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Here is my application-staging.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://docker_webstore_db_staging:3306/webstore
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=my-secret-pw-staging
```

Here are the commands I used to setup containers:

```
docker run --name docker_webstore_db_dev -e MYSQL_DATABASE=webstore -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -p 3306:3306 -d mysql
docker network create docker_webstore_network_staging
docker run --net docker_webstore_network_staging --name docker_webstore_db_staging -e MYSQL_DATABASE=webstore -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -p 3390:3306 -d mysql
./gradlew clean assemble
docker build -t webstore-backend .
docker run -d -p 8090:8080 --net=docker_webstore_network_staging --env spring_profiles_active=staging --name=webstore-backend-staging webstore-backend
docker logs <container id>
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: the table `users` was not (yet) created. Can you please share the setup for the MySQL database container?

Comment: Updated the setup.

Comment: I asked for the setup of the MySQL container, not the spring configuration...

Comment: My mistake I just uploaded the commands.

Comment: I am surprised you get a connection at all; the passwords for `root` do not match. --- If you do not auto-generate the ddl (e.g. by setting `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=drop-and-create`), the table `users` is not created and thus not present. The [`hub.docker.com` page for the MySQL image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) shows how a sql-script can be run at container startup (search for "Initializing a fresh instance").

Comment: I do get a connection but I forgot to update the password in the post. If I understood correctly from the post, I need to have .sql files in my project to create the tables in my database when docker is ran and they will be generated and filled with data? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Or enable ddl-auto generation in spring-boot (but this is not recommended for production settings).

Comment: Thank you! I just added all the necessary .sql files and now it is successfully creating the tables but they are still empty.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm overseeing something as your setup is kind of chaotic, but it seems to me that you're running two MySQL containers:

- docker_webstore_db_dev on port 3306 of your machine and
- docker_webstore_db_staging on port 3390 of your machine.

But your Spring configuration says to connect to docker_webstore_db_staging on port 3306.

I would also suggest to check the following things:

1. is the right profile activated? This is printed somewhere near the ASCII-art Spring Boot splash screen on server start
2. is auto-ddl generation activated? Otherwise, tables will not be auto-created of course

Comment: The port can be ruled out since both the application and the database are running in a container each, and on the same network. The database-container `docker_webstore_network_staging` exposes `3306`, and the application connects to `docker_webstore_db_staging:3306`. Furthermore, if the application would connect to a non-opened port, the application would report a different error (something along the line `ERR_CONNECT`). The error message shown indicates that a connection could be established, but the table `users` was not found.

Comment: From Docker docs: "The format of the --publish command is [host_port]:[container_port]"
So, he is exposing port 3306 of the container to 3390 of the "outside world". 

As I've never really worked with docker networks: shouldn't publishing ports be obsolete in this case when both containers are connected using that bridge network?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with it. I have the db port normally exposed during development, so I can connect tools to it (e.g. the database integration of intelliJ). The dockerized application doesn't need it.

Comment: alright, then I understand the behavior. Thank you!